# Can I test out App Actions without publishing my app to Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am following [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions/#0) to create some App Actions and be able to use my app via Google Voice Assistant.

It says that I have to upload my app to Google Play as an internal release.
So the question is:

**Can I implement App Actions and deeplinks for them, build an APK locally, install it via ADB and test it without interacting with Play?**

As I understood, Google Play takes care of enabling the actions in the Google Voice Assistant, but I may be wrong, since the documentation was not very clear for me.

Comment: Have you looked at https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/test-tool ?

Comment: @Pierre it still does require interacting with Play :(

Comment: It actually works without logging in to play, just by logging into the plugin and on the emulator. On the emulator you can trigger the action only through the plugin, talking to the assistant directly won't trigger the action. But at least one can verify it works